# How to find out the static IP address of a device?

Tags: networking, ip, nmap

I have got an IP camera which, according to the manual, is supposed to have static IP address 192.168.1.110. To connect to it (and change the network settings) I configured my laptop to have static IP 192.168.1.1/255.255.255.0 and connected it *directly* to the camera (without any routers/switches in between).

The laptop indicated that wired network was connected. But 192.168.1.110 was not pingable. So I did:

```
nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24
```

but that came back with the laptop's IP only.

To rule out the possibility that the camera could have 192.168.1.1 as well, I changed the laptop's address to 192.168.1.2 and tried again. Same result — the laptop's IP only.

Presumably, the camera has been set up for some other private network — could be 192.168.0.0/16, 172.16.0.0/12 or whatever. Apart from questioning the vendor/supplier, is there a neat/quick way to find out which IP/network the camera has been set up for?

The vendor actually recommends to use an app called AjDevTools (for Windows) but I am not convinced to bother turning my virtual Windows on as I don't know how that app could possibly help if the above steps with `nmap` did not.

Comment: Have you tried to connect, regardless of pingable? The camera may not respond to ping requests. If you cannot connect, have you checked if there is a way to "factory default" it? Have you contacted the mfg's tech support?

Comment: @C.M. Yeah I tried `telnet <IP> 80/443`, no response. The tech support simply suggests AjDevTools for Windows.

Comment: Also, how did you connect directly to it? Not all network interfaces are meant to--or capable of--directly connecting like that. You may need at least a hub in between.

Comment: @C.M. Just simple Ethernet cable. The laptop OS showed it was 100 Mbps, so the link was definitely on.

Comment: I would not trust that enough to draw that conclusion. Put i on a hub, wih at least one other device ou know works, and see if you can show both the laptop and the other known-working device. Part of problem solving and diagnostics is to avoid making assumptions--rule out and eliminate with certainty.

Comment: @C.M. The first thing I did was to plug it into my local network where a router gives away DHCP addresses. It did not grant any new leases. ..110 was not pingable, everything else worked as usual. I think the camera _would_ behave as it is behaving if it was set up with another private network, wouldn't it? So, the question is basically how to find out _what/which_ that network is — apart from manually trying all possible private networks. Maybe there is a network bruteforce tool or something?

Comment: You are trying to diagnose the problem at a later stage. "Is he dead, Jim?" "No, he's still warm, therefore, he must _not_ be dead!"  "Jim, if he recently died, he may sill be warm... Have you checked for a pulse?" "No need to, he's still alive--he's warm!" Step back, and troubleshoot from step one, not step five or ten.

Comment: @C.M. Well, I think I have enough evidence that the camera is not dead. It makes a sound when powered, it has infrared lights on in the dark, and, most importantly, the laptop recognises network link ON when it is connected (and back OFF when disconnected). What is your step 1 that you think I missed?

Comment: I was not suggesting the camera is dead, only that you need to step back. It is a _camera_, not a router, nor a laptop. It's hardware and software may not be as robust. The TCP/IP networking stack programmed in to it may be incomplete or lacking features. A patch cable may not be enough--you may need a crossover cable. Even a crossover cable may not be enough, you may need to put a hub between it and other devices (and use patch cables in that case, not crossover cables). All those are simple things to try without having to scan the millions of possible IP addresses/networks to find it.

Comment: Next, is there any indication _from the camera_ to give you confirmation that it has established a physical network connection? An LED or indicator in the LCD display? All this is before even considering it's IP address or even if it is DHCP capable.

Comment: @C.M. Why do you consider it is more likely that the camera requires cross cables/hubs etc. than that it simply has some other network configured than 192.168.1.0? Any special hardware requirements would have been in the manual, but there are none. I have configured many IP cameras before, and this one does not appear to require something different.

Comment: Then you are on your own. Most users here will have very little desire to help you if you are not willing to do simple troubleshooting and verification to correctly identify what and where the problem exists. You have per-determined that the problem is the IP address, when even the manual tells you it is a specific static IP--yet that is not working, is it? Is the manual wrong? If so, only the manufacturer can help you there, we cannot. Is your laptop OS wrong? If so, then you need to discuss that as a bug with them. Why don't _you_ tell me, what other possibilities could exist?

Comment: @C.M. As far as this question is concerned, I am happy to assume that the camera _is_ configured with a network other than 192.168.1.0, and I am asking how to find which one that is. Any other speculations are welcome but not necessarily necessary.

Comment: In absence of any other indication from the manual or manufacturer, you will: (1) have to try every possible network address (billions of them) until you find it, or (2) learn how to use Wireshark to sniff any possible packets from the camera and extract the IP/MAC from that. There is no simple command to do any of that.

Comment: To add: Or (3) Do as their tech support suggests, and fire up a Windows VM, run their software, and hope it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wireshark rulez.

As suggested by C. M. in the comments to the question:

> use Wireshark to sniff any possible packets from the camera and extract the IP/MAC from that

So, I started sniffing the network interface and plugged the cable in. Among a bunch of weird stuff there were a few incoming packets from some 192.168.**254.24**. Upon changing the laptop's static network configuration to 192.168.254.1, I was able to connect to the camera at 192.168.254.24. Bingo!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the DCHP server to give the IP you want to the mac address of the camera. Usually you can set it via your router.

You can read more here as well:
https://linuxapt.com/blog/36-how-to-configure-dhcp-on-linux

Comment: That only works if the camera requests an address via DHCP (most do, but I would think that the camera manual would clearly state that it does, and not state a specific static IP address...)

Comment: The MAC address is unknown (not stated anywhere on the camera or on the packaging). Is there a way to find it out via the connected network cable?